# Is there a way to like-dislike and pin-unpin comments through YouTube API v3?

Tags: api, youtube

I've explored [official documentation about the comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) but I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Is there a way to like or dislike the comment to a video with YouTube API v3?
And if I'm the owner of the video, I'm able to pin-unpin the comment. How to do that through the API?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API for such actions.